# imeOptions does not work with MultiAutoCompleteTextView and textMultiLine

Tags: android, textview

I am using a `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` with `imeOptions`="actionDone".
I need the text to be with autocomplete and multiline therefore I am setting the `inputType` to both.

The problem is that when the keyboard opens I don't see a `DONE` button as I expected. I can only see `DONE` when I change the `inputType` to "text".

This is how field looks like currently:

```xml
<MultiAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/recording_desc"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:completionThreshold="2"
    android:dropDownAnchor="@+id/autoCompletionArea"
    android:dropDownSelector="@color/white"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textAutoComplete"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:popupBackground="@color/offwhite"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/sharing_description_text_size"/>
```

Any ideas how to fix this so I can have both the field mutliline and get the imeOptions to work as I expect?

Answer (score 1):

i know this is too late to answer but this is for those who still need help about

```
android:imeOption="actionDone"
```

not working for `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`.
write the following line in java class where you want to use the `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`.

```
multiEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
multiEditText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

and in xml file add the following line

```
android:inputType="textImeMultiLine"
```

this will work fine. :)